# Automaticaly add new entry into a table codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am making a program that counts meal allowance for every employee based on their attendance. Here's the data i have right now, a table called **attendance** . This table is filled from a csv file i import, here's my code for importing the csv

```
function uploadData()
{
    $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
    // Ignore header line
    $header = fgetcsv($fp);
    // Array to store the partial records
    $attendance= [];
    while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp))
    {
        // Key to identify first part of record (Name and date)
        $key = $csv_line[1]."/".$csv_line[3];
        if ( isset($attendance[$key]) ){
            $start = $attendance[$key];
            // Extract data from first part of record and add in end date from current row
            $data = array(
                'id_attend' => $start[0] ,
                'emp_code' => $start[1],
                'emp_name' => $start[2],
                'date' => $start[3],
                'time_in' => $start[4],
                'time_out' => $csv_line[4],
            );
            $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('attendance', $data);
            // Remove partial record
            unset($attendance[$key]);
        }
        else    {
            // Store partial record
            $attendance[$key] = $csv_line;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
    $data['success']="success";

}
```

and here's my table

---

```
|   id_attend   |   emp_code   |   emp_name   |   date   |  time_in |  time_out  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0001        |   brw        |   brown      |01.01.2001|  07.00   |    20.00   |
|   0002        |   cny        |   cony       |01.01.2001|  07.00   |    20.00   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to count how much days they attend and keep it into my database. I already have a table as a container called **allowance**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id_allowance(auto increment)|emp_code|emp_name|days_attended|allowance|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          0001              |   brw  |  brown |       1     |  30.00  |
|          0002              |   cny  |  cony  |       1     |  30.00  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there any way the allowance will be auto generated and updated everytime i import new csv file? because the allowance table supposed to be empty in the first place and really depended on the attendance table

Comment: This question is not related to PHP or CodeIgniter. You can do this with a custom query to get all information you need using a view table.

Comment: my bad, sorry for the mistake. is it view table is the answer? because i also need those data in my database, not only for a view function @Xartrick

Comment: You want to update `allowance` each time you import into `attendance`?

Comment: @Kisaragi Something like that, but the main problem is i don&#39;t know how to fill the allowance since it should be empty before i import the csv

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, sounds like you can just import your csv, then `select * from allowance where emp_code = value` and insert if there are no results, or update if there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to create a trigger in MySQL so when new data will insert in **attendance** table at that time same query will automatic generate and run for the **allowance** table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS allowance_insert_trigger;
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER allowance_insert_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON attendance FOR EACH ROW
 begin
   DECLARE days_attandence varchar(10);
   SELECT count(*) INTO days_attandence FROM attendance WHERE emp_code=NEW.emp_code GROUP BY date;
   INSERT INTO `allowance` ( `emp_code`, `emp_name`, `days_attended`, `allowance`) VALUES ( NEW.emp_code, NEW.emp_name, days_attandence, '30.00');
 END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You want to write trigger like this and here I have put static value for allowance but you can put your own calculated value there.

Comment: the formula is days attended * general allowance (we got the general allowance from a table that contains the number)

Comment: soo, can you help me? ._. @Parth Viramgama

Comment: is it possible to make the "days attended" automatically count the data from selected range?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting can you please explain in brief ?

Comment: So basically i want to count how many days attended by each employees, that requires me to count the data from **attendance** and put it into "days_attended" from allowance. So can you add something to the query? Because i have no idea how to._.